# Why do I need to use 'parametersetname' with a PowerShell switch?

Tags: powershell

My question is about the parameter field 'parametersetname' and it mysterious need to be included.

I have this PowerShell (v3) script called test.ps1:

```
param([parameter(parametersetname="anything")][switch]$foo=$false)
$foo.IsPresent
```

If I run it in the PowerShell IDE cmd line like this:

```
.\test.ps1
```

I get

```
> False
```

whereas calling it with

```
.\test.ps1 -foo
```

I get

```
> True
```

Both good. 
However it has taken me a while (ages) to realise that for switch to work, I must add this descriptor "parametersetname".

Because if I repeat my test, but omit "parametersetname" like this:

```
param([parameter][switch]$foo=$false)
$foo.IsPresent
```

When I run this:

```
.\test.ps1
```

I get error:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'foo'. Cannot convert the "False" value of type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter" to type 
>   "System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute".

whereas calling it with

```
.\test.ps1 -foo
```

I get

> Missing an argument for parameter 'foo'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute' and try again.

Does anyone know why?

What magic is 'parametersetname' doing?

Comment: Magic in parenthesis: `[parameter()]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to use parametersetname, but you do need the brackets after Parameter.

If you omit the brackets it seems that powershell is reading it as type information for the parameter and trying to cast the parameter to that type, instead of treating it as a parameter attribute.

```
param([Parameter()][switch]$foo=$false)
```

Works as does

```
param([switch]$foo=$false)
```

Comment: You don't need to set the default value to false, a boolean will of course default to false with no assignment.  Although makes no practical difference.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers why? I want default behaviour, that can be turned off. My specific example is that I want to replace a version string that is normally formatted (in my stuff) with dots. But I have some older stuff (MFC) that uses commas. The switch seems the perfect choice to me. Could you expand on your reasoning?

Comment: If it makes no practical difference, then I'll leave in as it removes any ambiguity in the code of what the default maybe.